# How do I convert a PDF document to a preview image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, pdf, lamp

What libraries, extensions etc. would be required to render a portion of a PDF document to an image file?

Most PHP PDF libraries that I have found center around creating PDF documents, but is there a simple way to render a document to an image format suitable for web use?

Our environment is a LAMP stack.

Comment: I would love to be able to do this and have the file have a `.jpg` extension. I tried the .htaccess AddHandler method and it didn't work.

Comment: Alternatives for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/50170/238253

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You need [`ImageMagick`](https://www.php.net/imagick) and [`GhostScript`](https://www.ghostscript.com/download.html)

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
?>
```

The `[0]` means `page 1`.

Comment: yes, it works. You can also do: $im->setResolution( 300, 300 ) for example to render your pdf at desire resolution.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if you're using google docs, and don't mind the iFrame, this suggestion might work (it's also a wp plugin) https://forrst.com/posts/PDF_thumbnails_with_Google_Docs-6G6

Comment: but how to include ImageMagick and GhostScript in php file

Comment: @LuisMelgratti Hmm, that `setResolution` thingy doesn't seem to work. I put it after the `$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');` line from Paolo's example. Doesn't seem to do anything. What if I wanted an image from a PDF with a width of say, 1500, a height to scale, and a high resolution? How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @think123 use `$im->thumbnailImage(1500, 0);` That will set your jpg image to a width of 1500 and retain scale. [See documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php#example-3301)

Comment: How long will it take to build Imagick, I can't wait much, still its building... 
having cofee :D

Comment: From my answer below - If you're loading the PDF from a blob this is how you get the first page instead of the last page: $im->readimageblob($blob);
$im->setiteratorindex(0);

Comment: @LuisMelgratti will it work in windows 7??? Is it possible to install in win 7??

Comment: I tried it however it gave me: "error no decode delegate for this image format `\path\filename.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532". I tried $exec = "convert -scale $width $source $dest";exec($exec); and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Did any of you felt this is slow ? I felt this very slow and wanted to use Ghostscript only which is more faster.. if any of you interested I wrote a wrapper for it https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino.i have tried your example but i am getting following error. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'UnableToOpenBlob `file.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657' in D:\xampp\htdocs\learn\index.php:39 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\learn\index.php(39): Imagick->__construct('file.pdf') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\learn\index.php on line 39

Comment: Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Set the image format to JPG otherwise the image may not render correctly in PNG. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: In case the Ghostscript link dies, here the Github page: https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases

Comment: I used this but opted to have the server serialize/cache the resulting thumbnail. The next time the API is requested to provide a thumbnail, it checks if a cached thumbnail is available and provides that by unserializing the resulting image. It has made thumbnail retrieval using this method incredibly fast and I'm not even storing them in a database. Would probably be even faster if properly stored in a DB.

Comment: "ImageMagick was not designed to securely handle untrusted PDF files. Enabling PDF file handling is dangerous if any malicious PDF files are ever processed." from https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-imagemagick-extension/

Comment: How to store this image in variable that can be directly use in `<img src=""/>`

Answer (score 38):

For those who don't have ImageMagick for whatever reason, GD functions will also work, in conjunction with GhostScript. Run the ghostscript command with `exec()` to convert a PDF to JPG, and manipulate the resulting file with `imagecreatefromjpeg()`.

Run the ghostscript command:

```
exec('gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r300 -sOutputFile=whatever.jpg input.pdf')
```

To manipulate, create a new placeholder image, `$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor(...)`, and bring in the current image. `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('whatever.jpg')`, and then you can use `imagecopyresampled()` to change the size, or any number of other built-in, non-`imagemagick` commands

Comment: To just get a image of the first page, add the switches -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 to the command.

Comment: If it's still not working, you might need to give the full path to the `gs` binary.

Comment: This looks like it is running a system command. What if the user uploads a file named `something;rm -rf /`?

Comment: If i want all page of pdf to convert into image. then how to do?

Answer (score 35):

You can also get the page count using

```
$im->getNumberImages();
```

Then you can can create thumbs of all the pages using a loop, eg.

```
'file.pdf['.$x.']'
```

Comment: (This should actually be a comment on Paolo Bergantino's answer)

Comment: smart answer. not given by other but you notice and wrote.

Answer (score 18):

Use the php extension [Imagick](http://php.net/imagick).
To control the desired size of the raster output image, use the [setResolution function](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php)

```
<?php    
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(300, 300);     //set the resolution of the resulting jpg
$im->readImage('file.pdf[0]');    //[0] for the first page
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
?>
```

(Extension on Paolo Bergantino his answer and Luis Melgratti his comment. You need to set the resolution before loading the image.)

Answer (score 11):

If you're loading the PDF from a blob this is how you get the first page instead of the last page:

```
$im->readimageblob($blob);
$im->setiteratorindex(0);
```

Comment: (This should actually be a comment on Paolo Bergantino's answer)

Answer (score 11):

You can also try executing the 'convert' utility that comes with imagemagick.

```
exec("convert pdf_doc.pdf image.jpg");
echo 'image-0.jpg';
```

Comment: Instead of pdf_doc.pdf, pdf_doc.pdf[0] is preferred.

Comment: convert is part of the package ImageMagick; try sudo yum install ImageMagick

Comment: If it's still not working, you might need to provide the full path to the `convert` binary.

Comment: `echo 'image-0.jpg';` returns a string.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of [PDFlib](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib) which is a [GhostScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/)  wrapper for php, advantage of using this library is, it is already tested and it does not require `ImageMagic`

Always `GhostScript` commands are faster than `ImageMagic` when it comes to pdf so you should either go for a GhostScript wrapper or pure GhostScript commands

```
$pdflib = new ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib();
$pdflib->setPdfPath($pdf_file_path);
$pdflib->setOutputPath($folder_path_for_images);
$pdflib->convert();
```

Comment: Hi, I am using your PDFlib to create PNG's from PDFs.

    $pdflib = new ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib();
    $pdflib->setPdfPath($pdf_file_path);
    $pdflib->setOutputPath($folder_path_for_images);
    $pdflib-
    >setImageFormat(\ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib::$IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG);
    $pdflib->setDPI(100);
    $pdflib->setPageRange(1,$pdflib->getNumberOfPages());
    $pdflib->convert(); 

Does PDFlib have an option to set the width and height of the created PNG files?

Comment: Hi, no PDFLib does not provide methods to manipulate images but you can do like this.
once you generated the pngs using PDFLib you can use another Image manipulation libraray like  
https://github.com/Treinetic/ImageArtist
to get your work done...

Comment: I will give a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Think differently, You can use the following library to convert pdf to image using javascript

http://usefulangle.com/post/24/pdf-to-jpeg-png-with-pdfjs

Comment: If I want to display the preview image in server how can we use that?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://github.com/scandel/pdfThumbnails.
I think you can upload the image thumbnail generated here alongside the actual file and save it, this way you will save more computational time on your server (since the thumbnailing process were done in a client-side computer).

Comment: And only receiving and allowing an image file is saver than using ImageMagick on untrusted PDFs.

Comment: The only problem with this solution: The necessary [pdf.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.228/pdf.min.js) is 328 KB in size.

Answer (score 3):

I install finished! It's worked!

You may be do base [install imagemagick](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2008/09/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-setup.html) on windows.

In `php (local)` use call `exec(<command line>)`
ex:

```
<?php
$pdf = "filename.pdf";
$info = pathinfo($pdf);
$file_name =  basename($pdf,'.'.$info['extension']);
echo $file_name;
$pdf = "filename.pdf[0]";
exec("convert $pdf convert-img/$file_name.jpg");    
?>
```

Besides, you may be use `class imagick` in [PHP Imagick class](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.imagick.php)

Thanks all helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple class I've written and used on a couple of projects.  It just wraps `imagick` and handles writing each page out to disk.  If anyone is still looking for an easy way to do this, [this link](https://github.com/snyderp/PES_File_PDF_Splitter) might be helpful.

Comment: Link-only answers are low value on StackOverflow because if the link moves or dies, the answer is rendered absolutely useless.  To improve your answer, the bulk of your solution should be hardcoded here.