# How to make PDF viewer in PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I want to open PDF file with PHP. Don't want to use Flash. Like google doc viewer. I just want to open PDF file. Can I do with PHP ?

Comment: are you opening it just to display it in a site/web app or are you  trying to read text from the PDF for other purposes?

Comment: If you just want to open up a PDF file with php, there are a set of PDF functions (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php).

Comment: I want to get some text from PDF. If PHP can do like google doc viewer, I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP cannot natively open and display a PDF file to the browser. In most cases you want to just send the file to the browser and allow the Adobe Reader to open and display the file. However, if you are looking to pull data out of the PDF itself, then the PDF function built-into PHP may be of some help.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

Answer (score 2):

You can't *BUT* 
You can make one with **PHP**

making a previews of each page
like google reader

this links may help you 
[How do I convert a PDF document to a preview image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)