# PDF Viewer for my web - PHP

Tags: php, pdf, viewer

I am searching for an opensource pdf viewer for my web-site

Searched for months and months. Is there any open source to view pdf in my web (without Flash).

On the other hand, the documents should be secure.

I have done a synopsis with the following urls (but no use)

1. http://embedit.in/
2. http://www.vuzit.com/
3. http://www.ajaxdocumentviewer.com/
4. http://flexpaper.devaldi.com
5. http://www.icepdf.org/
6. https://docs.google.com/viewer
7. http://www.snowbound.com/
8. http://www.mygazines.com
9. http://www.issuu.com/business
10. http://www.box.net
11. http://viewer.zoho.com/

I want both download and print option for my pdf viewer.

Comment: are you looking for an open source pdf read and print library w.r.t php ?

Comment: The least you could do is format your question decently :/

Comment: @Ravikiran - yes ofcourse. could you help me?

Comment: A PDF viewer "without Adobe" pretty much means HTML and CSS and/or images. This conflicts quite a bit with "should be secured". Maybe you can clarify your requirements and ideal solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make PDF viewer in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025586/how-to-make-pdf-viewer-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its already answered @ [How to make PDF viewer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025586/how-to-make-pdf-viewer-in-php)

Additionally, you may also want to check [PDF Functions - php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php)

Answer (score 0):

1) Download zip file from: 
**https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/archive/master.zip** and unzip to `http://yourhost/myfolder` (or wherever you have hosted it).. 
2) After extraction, in **myfolder/web** folder, open **viewer.js** and change **DEFAULT_URL** to your **example.pdf** path.
3) open in your browser `http://yourhost/myfolder/web/viewer.html`

Comment: This same link was already posted 2 years ago.

Comment: Try https://pdfobject.com/