# How to create a thumbnail from PDFs or various other document files?

Tags: php, pdf, thumbnails

What would be the best way to create a thumbnail image from a PDF or various other document files?

Comment: could be merged with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565344

Comment: better one to merge with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410859/generate-documents-thumbnails-pdf-word-spreadsheets-etc-from-within-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find some useful answers in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php).

Comment: actually, that looks rather like a duplicate than a related question. good find.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the related question

Comment: @Gordon: Well, that one is specific to PDFs while this one also says "various other document files" but they are certainly very similar.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to be able to "rasterize" the file format to a bitmap at the desired resolution.  PDF is Not Easy to render (properly that is).  Depending on what those "other formats" are, the difficultly could be anywhere between "trivial" (a bitmap format would just need to be scaled) and "Nigh Impossible" (some proprietary format... MathLab or some such).

How to do all that in PHP?  Not really my department.  But at least now you know what questions to ask (though none of this might be news to you).

Comment: From the linked question[s], ImageMagick can handle a whole pile of different image formats, scaling, etc.  Pretty slick.  Not so sure about things like ".doc" and it's ilk.