# Creating files of PDF's thumnails

Tags: php, imagemagick

As an extension to this question: [How do I convert a PDF document to a preview image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
echo $im;
?>
```

How do I use the code from the above question to create files on the server of the PDF's. The above code only displays the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you could use `imagejpeg();`. Read about it in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php).

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
echo $im;
imagejpeg($im, 'thumbnail.jpg');
?>
```

Edit: If the above doesn't work, you could try `$im->writeImage('thumbnail.jpg');`. I'm not familiar with Imagick, but according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-writeimage.php), it might work. Worth a shot? :P

Comment: As far as I know, an ImageMagick object does not work with GD calls.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Updated with a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, writeImage worked. See my answer for my code example.

Answer (score 0):

The code I used is as follows. It may help others with similar problems:

```
<?php
$file ="/var/www/assets/files/product_brochures/product_catalouge.pdf[0]";
$im = new imagick($file);
$im->setResolution( 100, 100 );   
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
$height=$im->getImageHeight();
$width=$im->getImageWidth();

$im->cropImage($width/2, $height, 0, 0);

if ($height < $width)
  $im->scaleImage(44,0);
 else
  $im->scaleImage(0,60); 

$im->writeImage('thumbnail.jpg');
?>
```