# Create Image from PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, imagemagick, tcpdf

I am generating a PDF using the TCPDF library and would like to convert the pdf to an image. Anyone know if this is possible with TCPDF itself (I've looked over the code but doesn't look possible)?

Looking at [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php) on here it appears the best method is to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - is that still the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick and Ghostscript would be the way to go to do that. I would assume that running the gs or convert commands from the command line is a bit more efficient since you dont have to load the imagemagick extension in PHP and it cuts the overhead from using abstraction classes for the extension.