# Can I get a preview for a PDF using HTML5 File API?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, filereader

I can set the `src` of an image to preview a dropped image file, but how about a pdf?

(If not a preview thumbnail, then how about file type icons at least?)

Comment: btw I meant a simple thumbnail preview

Comment: in ASP.NET MVC 3 `<embed src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + a.Location + "?#scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0")">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to implement this is to get the file type when you are doing the upload of the pdf and save. when you displaying the record you can just do a check to see the file type

Comment: Are you talking about matching icons or an actual preview?

Comment: i'm talking about matching icon but you can have a preview image too just check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: So it has to be created server-side? There is no way for the File API to grab a preview from windows or anything like that?

Comment: i've search myself none that i can find

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, PDF files are not web compliant, so we have to make use of external libraries which help us deal with these type of files. A very well-known is the [Mozilla PDF JS library](https://rawgithub.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js).

Now do a preview of the first page of the pdf file.

```js
//
// Asynchronous download PDF as an ArrayBuffer
//
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
var pdf = document.getElementById('pdf');
pdf.onchange = function(ev) {
  if (file = document.getElementById('pdf').files[0]) {
    fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(ev) {
      // console.log(ev);
      PDFJS.getDocument(fileReader.result).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
        //
        // Fetch the first page
        //
        // console.log(pdf)
        pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
          var scale = 0.5;
          var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
          //
          // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
          //
          var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;
          //
          // Render PDF page into canvas context
          //
          var task = page.render({
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
          })
          task.promise.then(function() {
            // console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
          });
        });
      }, function(error) {
        // console.log(error);
      });
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mozilla/pdf.js/gh-pages/build/pdf.js"></script>

<canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<input id='pdf' type='file' />
```

Comment: `PDFJS.disableWorker = true;` is irrelevant to the answer -- you can remove it.