# can any binary file be converted to image in php

Tags: php, binary, preview

Can one binary files be converted to another(in fact to image),

like 
a **pdf** to **image**,
a **doc** to **image**,
a **xls** to **image** etc...

The whole idea is to present a preview to the user while downloading the file.
like suppose we have a doc file if user hover on it or clicked on the preview
button we show users **preview** of a file.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I believe there is the same question already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: I'm sorry, the question I linked above is about PDF files only.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem
convert pdf / doc to images for preview

you need to install 
- ImageMagick
- GhostScript

**Create GIF Thumbnail of First PDF Page**

```
<?php
    //the path to the PDF file
    $strPDF = "my_pdf.pdf";
    exec("convert \"{$strPDF}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 \"output.gif\"");
?>
```

**Create JPEG Thumbnails of ALL Pages Within PDF**

```
<?php
    //the path to the PDF file
    $strPDF = "my_pdf.pdf";
    exec("convert \"{$strPDF}\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 \"output.jpg\"");
?>
```

**Create Large PNG 1024px Image of First PDF Page**

```
<?php
    //the path to the PDF file
    $strPDF = "my_pdf.pdf";
    exec("convert \"{$strPDF}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 1024 \"output.png\"");
?>
```

**Create Large PNG 1024px Images of ALL Pages Within PDF**

```
<?php
    //the path to the PDF file
    $strPDF = "my_pdf.pdf"; 
    exec("convert \"{$strPDF}\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 1024 \"output.png\"");
?>
```

Comment: Abhishek J - how to convert a document (.doc) file or a .xls file ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do this programmatically without writing/implementing an entire rendering engine, which would be slow, difficult, and not particularly effective.

Instead, what you need to do is take a screen capture yourself and crop/resize it to whatever dimensions you wish.

Incidentally, if you are using Windows, holding `ALT` when you press the `prt scn` button will capture only the active window, which might make this easier.