# create thumbnail of uploaded pdf in joomla

Tags: php, pdf, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to create a thumbnail of a PDF. I am not able to create thumbnail. In raw PHP it works but in Joomla it's not working. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
$uploadPath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_ets_fast_track/assets/buildings/' . $filename;
$fileTemp = $file['tmp_name'];

if(!JFile::exists($uploadPath)){

    //name the thumbnail image the same as the pdf file
    $pdfWithPath = $uploadPath;

    $thumbDirectory = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_ets_fast_track/assets/buildings/';
    $thumb = basename($filename, ".pdf");

    //add the desired extension to the thumbnail                                        
    $thumb = $thumbDirectory.$thumb.".jpg";

    //execute imageMagick's 'convert', setting the color space to RGB and size to 200px wide
    exec("convert $pdfWithPath[0]  $thumb");

}
```

Comment: Have you defined `new imagick(' ... ');` anywhere?

Comment: no..I did not mentioned any where new imagick();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: @lodder while i doing as sample in using core php it is working but same code i written in joomla it is not working.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, not on the ball today. Ignore my previous comment. You do realise you have put `!` before `JFile` so your code will only run if the path **doesn't** exist

Comment: Yeah I tried without "!" also. Still its not working.

Comment: I will give this code a test in a bit and come back to you.