# prevent automatic file download and display file in php form using iframe

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to display doc or docx or pdf kind of file in php code.Here is my code,

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/sample/sampl1/resource/upload/resumes/1406263145_resume sample.docx"
style="width:820px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

in localhost...

When i load the form,the given docx file is downloading automatically and the file is not view in a php form...So any one can help me?

Comment: do you mean a thumbnail preview?

Comment: Not like that..Already i uploaded docx file...Now i need to show it in an light box.

Comment: i don't how on docx, but here is some how [pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php) lying here on SO

Answer (score 1):

To view document files (`doc`, `docx`, etc), you can use either the [Zoho Viewer](http://www.jawish.org/blog/archives/395-ZOHO-Viewer-plugin-for-jQuery.html) or [Google Docs Viewer](http://www.jawish.org/blog/archives/394-Google-Docs-Viewer-plugin-for-jQuery.html) jQuery plugin.