# How Can I create an image thumbnail during upload a PDF file in PHP or CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am uploading a PDF file. At the time of upload, I want to create a thumbnail image of the first page, and also want to save the file name into the database and file into a folder.  How can I do this?

Comment: refer this link

   

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: The ghostscript is an .exe file. How I use this on my site :(

Comment: Improved your title and fixed some grammar issues