# Imagine (imagick) can't open pdf with page parameter

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, silex, php-imagine

I use Imagine in a Silex environment,

In a main objective to create thumbnails from PDF files, I choose the [romainneutron/Imagine-Silex-Service-Provider](https://github.com/romainneutron/Imagine-Silex-Service-Provider) to do [this kind of PHP  ImageMagick conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php).

Everything is **OK** when I use the Imagick driver and when I open a pdf file without parameter :

**bootstrap.php :**

```
$app->register(new ImagineServiceProvider(), array('imagine.driver' => 'Imagick'));
```

**aController.php** :

```
 $path = "/path/to/file/";
 $filename = "aFileame";


 $image = $app['imagine']->open(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).$path.$filename.".pdf")
                         ->resize(new Box(160, 240))
                         ->save(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).$path."/thumb/".$fileName."_thumb@2x.png")
                         ->resize(new Box(80, 120))
                        ->save(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).$path."/thumb/".$filename."_thumb.png");
```

But if I I try to **just open the first page** of the document ( **.pdf[0]** ) :

```
$image = $app['imagine']->open(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).$path.$filename.".pdf[0]")
```

I have got an exception :

```
InvalidArgumentException in AbstractImagine.php line 67:
File /path/to/file/aFileame[0] does not exist.
```

Thanks for the help.
Julien