# Laravel - Thumbnail Generator Installation

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project that needs files like docx, xlsx, pptx, and pdf to generate a thumbnail. I can't see any tutorials that may be helpful enough for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! the package you are referring to is a python library.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any package that may help my project?

Comment: For pdf there is one definitely please follow this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)