# How can i add watermark to the pdf, image and docs in my angular application? Any library is there?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to add watermark to the pdf and image before getting downloaded by the user. I'm not able to find correct package for that. Also i don't know how to use pdf.js in my angular application.

Comment: Refer this example for how to use pdf.js in Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548288/how-to-use-pdf-js-in-angular-2-4-5