# Get a PDF catalog image

Tags: html, css

Is there possible way to get the first page image out of PDF file when I add it to my page? For example; I want to make a list of my PDF catalogs and as a cover use its image.  And when a user clicks on it, he is moved to the PDF file.

I  need to add images manually or this can be done some how using a PDF file int just a html code ?

I want something like this. 
[image: PDF catalogs with images]

Hope you get my idea

Comment: Yes you can do this with Imagick. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am looking for

Comment: You can make it *on-the-fly* is needed: https://bl.ocks.org/palerdot/bf0c52d84aa046a6963c

Comment: @Justinas Did it work on all browsers ?

Comment: Yes, it does work.