# How to run view in the background in the CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, curl

I have to run the view in the background. Below code is displaying both views on the single page.

My project is just filling the form and after filling the form display the PDF in 300*400px in the image(only display the half pdf)

Explain
What I am doing is, I have a registration form. After filling the registration form I have to call the URL in the background that URL will generate the PDF of it(PDF will not display to the student)then I have to pass the PDF URL which is generated to take the screenshot of it and screenshot of that image will display it in the view page.

This logic I am trying it. Or is there any other Idea?

```
public function generate_img(){
$session_stud_id=$this->session->userdata['student_session']['stud_id'];//student session id
$bg_link['bg_link']='index.php/Invoice/index/'.$session_stud_id;
$view_a=$this->load->view('test', $bg_link);//sending $bg_link to test view page and I have to run this view in the background
$req = curl_init();
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_URL,$view_a);
curl_exec($req);
$this->load->view('invoice_generate', $background_url_link);//What variable I have to use here? background URL i have to send it to other view page
}
```

Screenshot code

```
<?php 
echo $siteURL=base_url($background_url_link);
//call Google PageSpeed Insights API
$googlePagespeedData = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=$siteURL&screenshot=true");
//decode json data
$googlePagespeedData = json_decode($googlePagespeedData, true);
//screenshot data
$screenshot = $googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data'];
$screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'),array('/','+'),$screenshot); 
//display screenshot image
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".$screenshot."\" />";
        ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run view in background"?

Comment: @NeilPatrao, Thanks for the reply, I mean run the view page in the background. Or is there any other idea?

Comment: @NeilPatrao, Is it possible to take the screenshot of the URL like mydomain.com/index.php/invoice/index/10. In this URL my PDF is displaying and that is not a webpage

Comment: See this https://web-capture.net/ and several other services online https://www.google.de/search?ei=TMoCWv_WHMLlaPyzpfAI&q=webpage+screenshot+free&oq=webpage+screenshot+&gs_l=psy-ab.1.4.0j0i67k1l2j0l2j0i67k1j0l4.43637.43637.0.45370.1.1.0.0.0.0.102.102.0j1.1.0..1..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.102....0.19TNesnVktM

Comment: Your answer could be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: I don't want to enter the URL in the text box and clicked on submit. I just need it default take the URL and create the screenshot

Comment: I don't want to use ImageMagick and GhostScript