# Is there any solution to convert from base64 text/plain format to png/jpg image in php and display image?

Tags: php

I upload a pdf then convert it into base64 text/plain format and save that base64 text into database.Now I want to convert from base64 text/plain format to png/jpg format and display that image.Is there any solution for it?

Comment: you cannot simple convert a bas64 encoded pdf to an image without any conversion. You need to convert the base64 pdf back to a pdf and use other ways to create a image from it. Here is an exaple of the conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: Thank you. I'll give a try.

Comment: Yes, write some code for that