# Convert pdf to images using PDFLib library

Tags: php, pdflib

I need to convert pdf to images, for this, I try to use [this library](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib)

I have `index.php` file with code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'PDFLib-master/src/PDFLib.php';


$pdflib = new ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib();
var_dump($pdflib); exit;
```

This not outputs anything, what may reason for this ?

p.s.

I know this is not full code for converting, just not get why `$pdflib` is not an object ?

Comment: Not sure about PDFLib, but another solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Comment: I have used Ghostscript for years in an automated production environment with great success.