# PDF thumbnail - OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, octobercms-builder

as I mentioned in title I'm using OctoberCMS and builder plugin in my project and I'm trying to generate thumbnail/preview or to convert pdf file to an image file which I will be able to display in fronted also. Is something like that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Go to Builder --> Choose plugin / Models / Forms-->fields.yaml
Click add control and choose "File upload". Name the field ex. "thumbnail"

You don't need a table column as October automatically handle this for you. You need to add the following to your plugin Model class:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'thumbnail' => 'System\Models\File',
];
```

Note that the name "thumbnail" identifier must be the same as your form "field name" See: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments